# Bootstrap Dropdown + Angular data-ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a little issue while trying to show some data (Villains/Villanos) in a drop down with a ng-repeat. I've been looking around and trying but I can't make it work. I have the following HTML:

```html
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.7/angular.min.js" </script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script> 
    // This function lets the dropdown button save the name of the Villain that it's selected.
    $(function(){
        $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
            $(".dropdown-toggle:first-child").text($(this).text());
            $(".dropdown-toggle:first-child").val($(this).text());
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="dropdown">
       <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle dropdown-suspects-sides" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Suspects
          <span class="caret"></span>
       </button>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
          <li class="suspect" role="presentation" data-ng-repeat = "villain in villains">
             <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> {{villain}}
             </a>
          </li>
       </ul>                        
    </div>

/* Controllers */

...

$scope.getVillains = function() {
   $http.get("/getVillains")
      .success(function(data) {
         $scope.villains = data  
      }
   )
};

...
```

As you can see, I'm trying to make a dropdown to show all the Villains I have. The items appear correctly if they're showed in a normal list so the items can be "used", but they're not appearing if I try to show them this way. I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong here but I can't guess what is it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: it'll be helpful if you created a plunkr or jsfiddle with this

Comment: using jquery with angular.. something smells. can you share your controller code

Comment: i agree with @HarishR. ng-if and ng-hide/ng-show would be better alternatives

Comment: I tried to make a jsFiddle but I couldn't make it look as I wanted. (I'm kind of new to all this stuff so it takes me time) :( I've added the controller that gets the villains so they can be used in the HTML.